# set selected/unselected image one at a time uitableview cell in sectioned table

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

i m having a simple section table view. I have added a button at the left side of image.This button is selectable.Only one button (each cell have single button of same type) can be selected at a time and selected button background image changes to a specific selected image, others button back ground image changes to deselect image.If you tap again on selected image it remains selected.
How ever i am not getting correct behaviour.
code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//  UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
CustomCellMasterCustomer *cell=nil;

static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Locations";
Customer *mCustomer;
cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell==nil){
//      cell=[self reusableContentWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell=(CustomCellMasterCustomer *)[self reusableContentWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.tag = indexPath;
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageDisabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 36, 30)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(viewDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

cell.aCustomer = mCustomer;//alok added

if (indexPath == self.mPreviousIndex)
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageEnabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageDisabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)viewDetail:(id)sender
{
CGPoint buttonOrigin = [sender frame].origin;
// this converts the coordinate system of the origin from the button's superview to the table view's coordinate system.
CGPoint originInTableView = [self.allCustomerTable convertPoint:buttonOrigin fromView:[sender superview]];

                             // gets the row corresponding to the converted point
                             NSIndexPath *rowIndexPath = [self.allCustomerTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:originInTableView];


CustomCellMasterCustomer *cell = (CustomCellMasterCustomer *)[self.allCustomerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:rowIndexPath];

[self fillDetailViewWithCustomerInformation:cell.aCustomer];

//change button background image


UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageEnabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.mPreviousIndex = rowIndexPath;
[self.allCustomerTable reloadData];
```

}

what wrong i am doing,
any suggestion

Comment: change this  [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageEnabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Because indexpath always recreate with same row and section number. It won't same as previous.

```
if (indexPath.row == self.mPreviousIndex.row && indexPath.section == self.mPreviousIndex.section)
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageEnabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

And this two line of code, not needed anymore

```
/* UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellLeftImageEnabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];*/
```

Comment: this is working however, row 0 at section 0 is behaving default, i mean image is selected by default, any suggestion why ? i think self.mprevindex is creating problem

Comment: if (indexPath.row == self.mPreviousIndex.row && indexPath.section == self.mPreviousIndex.section && self.mPreviousIndex!=nil)

Comment: @Alok Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add a button out side the `if` block. In `UITableView` cells will be reused, if the cell is reused and at already has a button added to `contentView` then you should not add one more on top of it. so create a custom cell and make the buttion instance visible outside the class by declaring the buttion property in `customCell.h`. Now check the condition -

```
if (selected)

{

    cell.button.backgroundImage = selectedImage;

}

else

{

    cell.button.backgroundImage = unselectedImage;

}
```